# IBM Worklight - how to share the login creds between tests in a customSecurityTest?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

The scenario:

I am authenticating users against Active Directory using com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule. It works.

I need also to share the user-supplied login credentials (just the username) with a second test in my customSecurityTest to populate a record in a Hazelcast data-grid. Is is possible for Adapter-based authentication to collection the information I am looking for? To illustrate my intent ...

```
    <customSecurityTest name="ADTest">
        <test realm="ADRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
        <test realm="AdapterDataGridRealm" step="2"/>
    </customSecurityTest>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter use WL.Server.getActiveUser("ADRealm"). You'll get user identity of the ADRealm. It should have userId (or any other custom property you might have set)